# Bootstrap popover not appearing in my ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to create a popover that shows when a button is pressed.  The button is in a loop and executes for many variables j.  Code mainly taken from the Bootstrap webpage.

My code is as follows:

```
<a href='#' class="btn btn-xs" data-container="body" style="float:right;
 margin-top:-1px;" role="button" data-toggle="popover_@j" 
 data-placement="top" data-trigger="focus" 
 data-content="Content">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

My View also contains:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="popover_@j"]').popover()});
</script>
```

When I run this code on the W3Editor, the popover appears.  However, in my project, no popup appears.

Any help on getting the popover to appear would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I have checked my z-value is sufficient for the popover, it's value is at 1060.

Comment: The problem might be that you are running the "script" component once (on doc ready) instead of after your button finishes "looping". Try using the javascript after the looping.

Comment: Thanks Kevin P, unfortunately, moving the script block has had no effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

use following html code:

```
<div class="forLinks" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" style="width: 75px;">
                        <div style="width: 22px; height: 22px; margin-top: 16px; margin-left: 21px; cursor: pointer;">

                            <img src="~/Modules/REBAR.PersonalizeList/Styles/Images/RelatedLinksBox.PNG" style="height: 22px; width: 22px; cursor: pointer; /*display: block; */" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 110px; height: 22px; margin-left: 50px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: -17px;">
                            <span id="SpanRelatedLinks" style="width: 85px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff;">Related Links</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="popover-content" style="display: none; margin-left: 5px">
                        @foreach (Accenture.Orchard.QuicklinkItemManager.Models.QuicklinkItemViewModel LinkItem in Model.QuickLinks)
                        {
                            <div class="popoverLinks"><a style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%;" class="AnchorLinks" target="_blank" href="@LinkItem.Url">@LinkItem.Name</a></div>
                        }
                    </div>
```

and jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    return $('#popover-content').html();
                }
            });

            $('.forLinks').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
                var element = $('.popover'),
                    style = window.getComputedStyle(element[0]),
                    left = style.getPropertyValue('left');
                var leftValue = left.replace("px", "");
                $('.popover').css('left', parseInt(leftValue) - 5);
            });

            $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
                    // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked 
                    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').length != 0) {
                        $('.forLinks').trigger('click');
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I implemented your code, but took out the foreach loop around the div class= "popover-content" and the image and associated div tags.  However, it does not result in a popover for my solution.

Comment: @fuzzii giving css code in another answer plz refer that and let me know if ur facing any other issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**add following css:**

```
.popover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1060;
    display: none;
    max-width: 276px;
    padding: 1px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: left;
    text-align: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    line-break: auto;
}

    .popover.top {
        margin-top: -10px;
    }

    .popover.right {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .popover.bottom {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .popover.left {
        margin-left: -10px;
    }

.popover-title {
    padding: 8px 14px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.popover-content {
    /*padding: 9px 14px;*/
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}

.AnchorLinks {
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
}

.popoverLinks {
    /*Added by prasad*/
    /*padding-bottom: 3px;*/
    height: 28px;
    border-bottom-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.popover > .arrow,
.popover > .arrow:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}

.popover > .arrow {
    border-width: 11px;
}

    .popover > .arrow:after {
        content: "";
        border-width: 10px;
    }

.popover.top > .arrow {
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
    border-top-color: #999;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}

    .popover.top > .arrow:after {
        bottom: 1px;
        margin-left: -10px;
        content: " ";
        border-top-color: #fff;
        border-bottom-width: 0;
    }

.popover.right > .arrow {
    top: 50%;
    left: -11px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    border-right-color: #999;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    border-left-width: 0;
}

    .popover.right > .arrow:after {
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 1px;
        content: " ";
        border-right-color: #fff;
        border-left-width: 0;
    }

.popover.bottom > .arrow {
    top: -11px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #999;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

    .popover.bottom > .arrow:after {
        top: 1px;
        margin-left: -10px;
        content: " ";
        border-top-width: 0;
        border-bottom-color: #fff;
    }

.popover.left > .arrow {
    top: 50%;
    right: -11px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-color: #999;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

    .popover.left > .arrow:after {
        right: 1px;
        bottom: -10px;
        content: " ";
        border-right-width: 0;
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }

.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}

    .fade.in {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

**html code:**

```
<div class="forLinks" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" style="width: 75px;">
                        <div style="width: 22px; height: 22px; margin-top: 16px; margin-left: 21px; cursor: pointer;">

                            <img src="~/Modules/REBAR.PersonalizeList/Styles/Images/RelatedLinksBox.PNG" style="height: 22px; width: 22px; cursor: pointer; /*display: block; */" />
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 110px; height: 22px; margin-left: 50px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: -17px;">
                            <span id="SpanRelatedLinks" style="width: 85px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff;">Related Links</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="popover-content" style="display: none; margin-left: 5px">
                        @foreach (Accenture.Orchard.QuicklinkItemManager.Models.QuicklinkItemViewModel LinkItem in Model.QuickLinks)
                        {
                            <div class="popoverLinks"><a style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%;" class="AnchorLinks" target="_blank" href="@LinkItem.Url">@LinkItem.Name</a></div>
                        }
                    </div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    return $('#popover-content').html();
                }
            });

            $('.forLinks').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
                var element = $('.popover'),
                    style = window.getComputedStyle(element[0]),
                    left = style.getPropertyValue('left');
                var leftValue = left.replace("px", "");
                $('.popover').css('left', parseInt(leftValue) - 5);
            });

            $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
                    // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked 
                    if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').length != 0) {
                        $('.forLinks').trigger('click');
                    }
                });
            });
});
```